# Java how to draw on JPanel from another method?

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paint

I want to use a method to get what you are trying to draw (getImage() method) but I cant figure out how to draw it in to the paint method.
Here it is so far:

```
public void getImage(String location,int x,int y,int size){
    Image image = new ImageIcon(location).getImage();
    //paint(image); Thats my question
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You shouldn't draw anything in a JPanel's `paint(...)` method but rather its `paintComponent(...)` method. You will want to read the tutorials if you want to succeed with this.

Comment: What do the `x`, `y` and `size` arguments mean, specifically?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, you can't do this easily. What you *can* do however is to force a repaint by calling the [`repaint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) method and then paint the new image in the paint method.

The code will look something like this:

```
private Image someImage;
public void getImage(...)
{
  someImage = new ImageIcon(location).getImage();
  repaint(); //will make java call the paint-method in a moment
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
  if(someImage!=null)
    //paint someImage here
}
```

There's a long article about how [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html) works. Be sure to read the very short chapter [Swing Painting Guidelines](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#swing_summary) which contains the most important take-aways.

Comment: You'll want to change that to a paintComponent method, not paint, regardless of what the OP is requesting.

Comment: Yes, that's a very valid comment. It's also described in the guidelines I linked to. I just tried to stay as close as possible to the original code fragment.

Comment: Why do I have to use paintComponent?

Comment: paint() invokes three other methods that create a JFrame it can lead to other, unknown issues if you just override paint() by itself:
http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a class that extends from JPanel and another class unrelated to it that describes the image you are trying to draw.

Let's say you have two classes, **Window** (that extends JPanel), and **Image** (where you load the image to be drawn in the JPanel)

If you want to draw an image from *Image* into the *Window* class you have to instantiate *Image* in the *Window* class.

*Image* should have a method in it that can be used in *Window* to draw the image in *Window* like so:

```
private void drawMe(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(someImage, x, y, null);
}
```

and in your *Window* class (that extends from JPanel) I recommend you override the paintComponent method, not paint. In that method you should call *Image*'s drawMe() method and pass Graphics as an argument. Like so:

```
private Image image = new Image("filePath.jpg", 10, 10); //based on the arguments you setup in the contructor

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    image.drawMe(g); //access Image's drawMe() method and pass graphics to it
}
```

All drawing and image location is handled by the *Image* class, all you'r doing with the *Window* class is making it show up on the JPanel.